# Stack-Smashing Protection error message does not contain program name

Tags: c, stack-smash

Here is a very ugly C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[10];
    memcpy(buffer,argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this program with Stack-Smashing Protection:

```
$ gcc -fstack-protector smash.c -o smash
```

Here is what I get during execution:

```
$ ./smash 01234567890
01234567890v?\??nr?!??U
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

The protection works fine but I do not understand why I see instead of `argv[0]`.

Comment: Which architecture of CPU is this running on?

Comment: Intel x86 32 bits. I have tried on 64 bits it is the same thing